# Powershell for each scripts not sequential

Tags: powershell, foreach

I have the following PowerShell for each statement that loops over a list of about 50 mailboxes and runs 2 scripts on each one. These 2 script take about a hour to complete. Because of the sequential nature of PowerShell this would take ~50 mailboxes * 1 hour = 50 hours.

Is it possible for PowerShell to run the script on each mailbox on the same time, in parallel?

```
Foreach($mailbox in $mailboxes){
    Write-Host "$(Get-TimeStamp) Start of adding contacts $mailbox"
        & $scriptPath -Mailbox  $mailbox.UserPrincipalName -ClientSecret $clientSecret -ClientID $clientID -TenantID $tenantID -CSVPath $csvPath
    Write-Host "$(Get-TimeStamp) Start of deduplicating contacts $mailbox"
        & $scriptPath2 -Mailbox  $mailbox.UserPrincipalName -ClientSecret $clientSecret -ClientID $clientID -TenantID $tenantID 
}
```

Comment: Based on the brief description of what those scripts are doing, an hour for one mailbox seems more than a little excessive. I'd focus my effort on why that part takes so long. I'd bet you can reduce each to a few seconds. Then you don't need to deal with complexity of parallel code at all.

Comment: The first script imports around ~6000 contacts and the second script cleans the duplicates in the contacts using both Microsoft graph.

Comment: So? That's not really that much data.

Comment: Isn't there a better option than importing 6000 contacts to each individual mailbox? How about using a common address book?  

Comment: A common address book isn't possible because of synchronization with external applications.

Comment: foreach-object -parallel in powershell 7

Comment: This refers to the path where ps1 script is stored.

Comment: Yes, I understand that but what is inside that it take half a hour? E.g. I would recomment using a [pipeline](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell-community/mastering-the-steppable-pipeline/). Things as exporting to a `csv` should not be wrapped but a part of that pipeline: `foreach-object -parallel { <your tasks> } | Export-Csv $csvPath`, See also [PowerShell scripting performance considerations](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/scripting/dev-cross-plat/performance/script-authoring-considerations).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using the `Start-Job`?

```
$jobs = @()

foreach ($mailbox in $mailboxes) {
    $job1 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        Write-Host "$(Get-TimeStamp) Start of adding contacts $mailbox"
        & $scriptPath -Mailbox  $mailbox.UserPrincipalName -ClientSecret $clientSecret -ClientID $clientID -TenantID $tenantID -CSVPath $csvPath
    }

    $job2 = Start-Job -ScriptBlock {
        Write-Host "$(Get-TimeStamp) Start of deduplicating contacts $mailbox"
        & $scriptPath2 -Mailbox  $mailbox.UserPrincipalName -ClientSecret $clientSecret -ClientID $clientID -TenantID $tenantID 
    }

    $jobs += $job1, $job2
}

# Wait for all jobs to finish and retrieve results (if any)
$jobs | Wait-Job
$jobResults = $jobs | Receive-Job

# Clean up jobs and display results if needed
$jobs | Remove-Job
$jobResults
```

Comment: Or the threadjob module.

Comment: Hi, I made a small addition by adding a -ArgumentList in each job but this got to the solution thanks!

Comment: Yup you can add the -ArgumentList too if you wish. I've kept it as close as the original script to make it easier to understand the logic changes I've applied.